# ionic dev app is not detecting the ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am testing my ionic application using the ionic Dev app in android. After updating ionic to the newest version, ionic dev app is not detecting the application though it detected earlier. Is it a problem with the ionic cli version? How can I solve this?

Comment: did you get any error or just its not detecting your app ? please provide more details so we can help you on this.

Comment: No any errors. Earlier before updating ionic 3 cli the Dev App detected the ionic app and I tested my app using that. After updating it is not just detecting the app. I did not try to downgrade ionic cli and try.